# Sort Collection By One Property, If Null, Sort By Different Property

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a typed collection of custom objects, that have two DateTime? properties, ExpirationDate and ExpirationDateExtended. I am trying to get the latest from this collection based on these properties. Normally, with one property, I just use the OrderByDescending method and get the first one. This is demonstrated in the below.

However, what I am trying to do is if the ExpirationDate property has a value (is not null), sort (OrderByDescending) by the ExpirationDate property, however if it does not have a value (null), then sort (OrderByDescending) by the ExpirationDateExtended property.

In the below, the myCollection variable represents a collection of my custom objects.

```
var latestExpirationDate = myCollection
.Where(item => item.ExpirationDate.HasValue)
OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate)
.Select(item => item.ExpirationDate) 
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the null coalescing operator

```
OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate ?? item.ExpirationDateExtended)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the field for `null` and then specify the field using a conditional operator like:

```
OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate != null ? item.ExpirationDate :
                                                        item.ExpirationDateExtended)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var latestExpirationDate = myCollection
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate ?? ExpirationDateExtended)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```